# Progress bar (upto 30 sec) using jquery + ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a form and apply button to the user. After user filling form data, user can click Apply button, on clicking apply button the data will be writing into one text file using shell script.

I need to display the progress bar while server is writing the data into text file. 
my code

```
     $(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
callGetTxt();

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    /*ajax call to add status*/
      var formData = $("form").serialize();             
      $.ajax({
        url: 'config_site',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;             
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);      
        },
        failure: function () {
          alert("Ajax request failed!!!");
        },error: function () {
          alert("Ajax request failed to update data!!!");
        }
    });  

});
```

Please help me

Comment: please add method "beforeSend" in $.ajax and write code for progress bar in that function. [jquery link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: can you give me an example, i am very new to jquery 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
$('#overlay').hide();
console.log( "ready!" );
callGetTxt();

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    /*ajax call to add status*/
      var formData = $("form").serialize();             
      $.ajax({
        url: 'config_site',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;             
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          $('#overlay').hide();
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
           $('#overlay').show();
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("Ajax request failed to update data!!!");
        }
    });  

});
```

**Add Html**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**ADD CSS**

```
#overlay{background-image: url('image url');background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50FFFFFF,endColorstr=#50FFFFFF);width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to display real progress of ajax response - it would be almost impossible to accomplish, as ajax has no knowledge of the server whatsoever: you just send a request and wait for an answer, you have no way of knowing how long will it take. So, the best thing you can do is just put some `waiting` animation, and remove it on request finish.

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    callGetTxt();

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        /*ajax call to add status*/
        var formData = $("form").serialize();             
        $("#waiting").show(); // some waiting gif animation, lots of them on internets.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'config_site',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;             
            success: function (result) {
              console.log(result);      
            },
            error: function () {
               alert("Ajax request failed to update data!!!");
            },
            complete: function () {
                 $("#waiting").hide();
            }
        });   
    });
});
```

P.S. jQuery `ajax` has no `failure` method.